# DML operation performance for large table with multiple projections in vertica

Tags: sql, query-optimization, vertica

I have table with 3billion records, and have 2 projections on the same. Currently delete operation is taking around 3-4 hours in daily loads.

So having multiple projections impacts data loads or DML operations in vertica. Or is there any other better way to tune the delete operation in vertica.

DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID = TABLE1.ID);
Table1 have 3b records while Table2 have 50k records.

Projection1 for Table1 have ID column while Projection2 dont have ID column in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more efficient, the statement should be:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM table2
);
```

But also that can be inefficient if `id` is not part of all projections of `table1`

Comment: Just a doubt on this -- Do we need to have ID in all projection, if we have that in any one of them will it not use that specific projection?

Comment: Remember that Vertica does not remove rows, but only marks them for deletion by adding a _delete vector_ . The delete vector uses the `WHERE` condition used for the deletion - the `ID` in your case. Read this part of the _Administrator's Guide_ : https://www.vertica.com/docs/12.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkDeletingPurging/BestPracticesForDELETEAndUPDATE.htm . In a nutshell, it needs both a two-pass navigation to add the delete vector to the non-optimised projection(s) and to evaluate the delete vector for the same.

Comment: Thanks for that! And: is your big table partitioned, by any chance? There might be a way to speed up the operation you need to perform by manipulating partitions instead of delete vectors